# PHP - a different open_basedir per each virtual host

Tags: apache, virtualhost, php, open-basedir

I've came across on this problem, I have a sever running apache and php. We have many virtual hosts but we've noticed that a potentially malicious user could use his web space to browse other user's files(via a simple php script) and even system files, this could happens due to the php permissions.
A way to avoid it is to set the open_basedir var in php.ini, yhis is very simple in a single host system, but in case of virtual hosts there would be a basebir per each host.

Ho can I set dis basedir per each user/host? is there a way to let apache hereditate php privileges of the php file that has been requested

E.G.
/home/X_USER/index.php has as owner X_USER, when apache read the file index.php it checks its path and owner, simply I'm looking for a system set php basedir variable to that path.

Thank in advance
Lopoc

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is possible to set `open_basedir` on a per-directory basis using the `php_admin_value` Apache directive.

Example from the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.sect.safe-mode.php):

```
<Directory /docroot>
  php_admin_value open_basedir /docroot 
</Directory>
```

**Re your comment:** yes, external commands are not affected by `open_basedir` - when calling `ls /` this is done with the rights the user account PHP runs under (often named `www` or similar). As far as I know, it is not possible to extend `open_basedir` to external commands.

In that case, I don't think the kind of protection that you're looking for is possible in a normal Apache/PHP setup. The only thing that maybe comes close is [running Apache in a chroot jail](http://www.faqs.org/docs/securing/chap29sec254.html). I haven't done this myself so I can't say anything about it - you'd have to dig in and maybe ask a question specifically about that.

Comment: yeah ok, but just a simple
   echo 'ls /'
still works even with this directive

Answer (score 1):

You can set many php.ini settings using the Apache configuration file.

See these related pages from the PHP manual:
- http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.sect.path-directory
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php

Answer (score 1):

chroot is a good idea. And now docker is more effective.

and open_basedir with "/docroot" is not security ,you should end with a "/" or PHP can access /docroot1