# Properly Set Permission to /home/user folder for webserver

Tags: security, permissions, centos, public-html

I'm currently setting up my own Linux server running CentOs 6.
I already know the basic commands etc. but I don't have much experience with apache/php security although I do have a lot of experience with PHP on itself.

So, to test the security on my server I wrote a PHP script that acts like a sort of "navigator". I can go one directory up, open the files, etc. etc.

The problem is, my tools allows me to go up till "/" and I am not very happy with this.
Although Apache is being run as "nobody" it seems like it can reach every folder and file on the whole server.

I tried to solve this like cPanel did it, but since I don't have cPanel I don't exactly know how this is done.

Basically I have this:

```
/home/account/public_html
/home/anotherAccount/public_html
```

I want to make it so that "anotherAccount" can not access the files of "account". Actually I would love it so "anotherAccount" can't even get outside it's own directory!

Yes, I know you are thinking: Install suPHP/fastcgi/suExec, but I can't do this because they are eating resources. I know it's possible without installing either one of them! I uploaded my script to some professional yet not very known webhost and I was able to go inside / with it, but not inside the home directories except my own. /home/ listed as empty!

How do I secure my home folders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `open_basedir` directive in your php.ini to restrict the script to a directory, see [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir).

If you want different sites to have different restrictions the PHP instances must have different values of `open_basedir`, which can be set up in apache on a per-virtual-host basis. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781185/php-a-different-open-basedir-per-each-virtual-host) in stack overflow for more details.

However, note that `open_basedir` does not apply to external commands executed using `system()` and friends. If you want to be safe from that it would be best to move on to running several instances of php-fpm as different users or using suPHP. One of the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14980929/php-file-upload-permissions) contains an explanation of how to set up the ownerships and permissions to only allow users access to their own files.