# How to disable access to parent directory of DocumentRoot?

Tags: php, apache, apache2, httpd.conf

I have an Ubuntu system hosting several websites. The `DocumentRoot` folder of each website is separate and has a different user. The paths are like this:

```
/<path_from_root>/websites/websiteA
/<path_from_root>/websites/websiteB
```

Let's assume that the respective users are *userA* and *userB*. Though, the *userB* doesn't have read access to the folder *websiteA*, the *apache* user does have the access. *userB* can simply write a php file like this in his directory:

```
<?php
$x=file_get_contents('../websiteA/config.php');
echo $x;
?>
```

This file will expose the **config.php** file to the *userB*. The key issue is that *apache* needs to have read access to both the folders for running the web services but the *userB* can exploit this to access *userA*'s files. How to prevent this from happening?

Comment: There should be a configuration option for each `<VirtualHost>` telling it which user to run it under if I recall correctly.

Comment: The [documentation of apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#virtualhost) doesn't mention any such option.

Comment: Nevermind, I was confusing it with nginx.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the php directive open_basedir in your apache or vhost config files for [individual settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781185).

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    <Directory /docroot>
        php_admin_value open_basedir /docroot 
    </Directory>
<VirtualHost>
```

so scripts within this path can not open files outside of it.

Comment: Thanks, just what i needed!

Comment: saves my day tvm

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into how Apache and PHP are connected on your machine. If you use the Apache module mod_php, as far as I know all PHP code is executed as the user Apache itself runs as. If you connect PHP with CGI (fcgi, fastcgi or something from that range), you can use [suEXEC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SuEXEC). With suEXEC, you can set the user that PHP should run as per virtual host.